# Heroku cannot recognize DELETE of HTML for Ruby on Rails application

Tags: html, ruby

I have a question about deploying an application on Heroku. When I use DELETE method to kill the current login session, Heroku will instead make a GET call. It works fine in my local apps and fails when deployed on Heroku. I have no idea what I should do under this scenario.

Here is the code in routes.rb:

```
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

Here is the HTML code in _header.html.erb:

```
<li>
    <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
</li>
```

Comment: What's the HTML rendered by that `link_to`? In other words, what's sent to the browser? Is it the same locally and on Heroku?

Comment: Looks like your assets are not compiled on Heroku. Could you try `heroku run rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: @tompave The HTML is the header of the application and after log out, the user should be linked back to the root page `log_out` and then `redirect_to root_url`

Comment: @Vasiliy Ermolovich I will try to do the precompile on Heroku. What does this line mean? I am a new learner of Ruby on Rails and thank you so much for helping me

Comment: @RunjieLu since you run your app in production mode on Heroku you need to compile your assets (that's how Rails expects them to be in production https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production). And you need to do it because when you use `method: :delete` in your link Rails uses JavaScript to send DELETE request since if you can't do it without JS with `<a>` tag.

Comment: @VasiliyErmolovich Should I include some new lines in the application.js before doing the precompile? Thanks a lot for sharing this document to me.

Comment: @RunjieLu I think everything is included in new application

Comment: @VasiliyErmolovich It works!! Thank you so much for helping!!

Comment: @RunjieLu awesome! I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it and other people could find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you run your app in production mode on Heroku you need to compile your assets. And you need to do it because when you use `method: :delete` in your link helper Rails uses JavaScript to send DELETE request since you can't do it without JavaScript with `<a>` tag.

So you need to run `heroku run rake assets:precompile` to compile them.